# Pull negative values from sheet 1 and place them on sheet 3

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to create a formula that does the following:

If sheet 3 column A:A matches sheet 1 column B:B and if sheet 1 column G:G has a value that is less than 0, return the negative value to column D of sheet 3 in its corresponding matching row.

Hope this makes sense.

I tried vlookup, but I think that's only part of what I need.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in D2:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$100=A2)*('Sheet1'!$G$2:$G$100<0)*('Sheet1'!$G$2:$G$100))=0,"",SUMPRODUCT(('Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$100=A2)*('Sheet1'!$G$2:$G$100<0)*('Sheet1'!$G$2:$G$100)))
```

And copy down.

You can adjust ranges but make sure the row references are equal.

Comment: I changed some of the formula you provided to include multiple rows. So instead of a range of $B$2:$B$100, I put $B$2:$B2000. I did that on every range you had above and that seemed to make your formula work so that it would include all of the negative values. However, is their a way to do this where it just does the whole column and isn't dependent on specific cell ranges? Like B:B for example? Also - is there a way to make the 0 result not appear and just be blank if the return value is 0? Thanks for your help! I would have never figured that formula out!

Comment: First you do not want to do full column references. It is an array formula and it would do over 3 million calculations per formula. So just set the range to include enough rows to include the max it will ever be. Second to change the 0 to blank I will edit it in a second.

Comment: glad I asked first :). I will set a maximum and if the rows increase, I guess I can always adjust the range maximum. Thanks again for your help!!!

Comment: It should enter blanks instead of 0 now